# Ext JS with C# Backend

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-applications, extjs, backend

Im currently starting a new WebProject. The plan is to generate the entire frontend via extjs and communicate with a C# .Net Backend (via ExtDirect !? )...

My problem is that i dont really know what VisualStudio Project Type i should use..
The backend should only handle the requests from the Ext JS (and communicate with an other EntityFramework Projekt though thats not a problem)... Are there any tutorials around? I didnt find something like that. I am not sure if i have to use an ASP Web Form Project because i didnt planned to use any ASP controls or something like that. Like i said i want the frontend to be generated by EXT JS only.

Please help. Im glad about any input :)

Comment: You need to take a look ASP.NET Web API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've built a project with ASP.Net MVC and extjs as the front end. You could also use something like a WCF service to handle your server side calls but the ASP.Net MVC framework works fine as well.

I used an Ajax proxy in my stores that call my ASP.Net controllers which then call the database and I return the result back as json.

I used this project [TraXPLORER = ExtJS 4 MVC + ASP.NET MVC 3 + CRUD + REST](http://techfacade.com/blog/2011/10/18/extjs-4-mvc-asp-net-mvc-3-crud-rest/) to help me get started.

You also may want to check out [Ext.Net](http://www.ext.net/) as it's a wrapper for the extjs library for .Net apps.